# Do I need to install fonts to convert text in my pdfs?

Tags: windows, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I'm playing around with some pdf's and there are some that don't have the text in the resulting images.

Two of these documents:

http://comptroller.nyc.gov/wp-content/uploads/documents/CAFR2013.pdf
 http://www.sfcontroller.org/modules/showdocument.aspx?documentid=4935

I've done a little googling and it seems like I might need to get some support for new fonts. Here's the blog post that makes me thing that:

http://tech.superhappykittymeow.com/?p=254

How do I go about getting the fonts I need and installing them on Windows 8?

Comment: Your links were malformed; please take care to check them before posting. I could locate the second example PDF, but not the first.

Comment: Sorry. I added the real link.

Answer (score 0):

OK that post about missing fonts refers to a *very* old fork of Ghostscript, you most certainly won't get an error with the current canonical version (the ESP fork was merged back to the trunk many years ago and no longer exists). You might get the wrong font, which can lead to text being garbled, but that's it.

The first URL you posted seems to be an HTML page, and the second one is incomplete so I get a 404 page.

If you want fonts to work with Ghostscript then you need to install them on *Ghostscript*, not Windows. Its true that when you install Ghostscript on Windows it will offer to add your current Windows fonts to the ones Ghostscript knows about, and adding new fonts to the same folder will (usually, but I haven't tried this on Windows 8) allow Ghostscript to see them too. But you can add them to GS without adding them to Windows and vice-versa.

You can also define a substitute font. Say you need a font called MyFont-Itaiic and you don't have it, but you do have YourFont-Italic, and you happen to know that they are the same except for minor flourishes. You could define YourFont-Italic as a substitute for MyFont-Italic.

As for obtaining the fonts, you can either rummage around the web to see if the font or a clone is freely available, or you can buy them from font foundries.

Comment: I've fixed the first link but the second one is working fine.

Comment: I don't like to sound picky but it would be helpful to have smaller example files, 300 page documents are not the easiest thing in the world to deal with.... So, what exactly is your problem ? (please be descriptive and precise, particularly in a 300 page document I'm not going to search for 'some text is missing') Also,how are you using Ghostscript ? What version, what command line ?

Answer (score 0):

The fonts reported "not embedded" in `documentid=4935` are Arial, Helvetica, Times, and Times New Roman (in several styles each). Those can safely be replaced with the standard fonts on your system: Arial and Times New Roman if on MS Windows, Helvetica and Times if on Mac OS X.

If you experienced this problem with one or more of the *other* fonts in the document (Helvetica Neue, Monotype Corsiva, Nyala), then the problem may be one of the programs in your workflow does not correctly recognize the embedded subsets of these fonts.

#### Addition

Checked the other document with Acrobat Pro: *all* of its fonts are embedded as a subset, so if your workflow is sound, you should not have seen any missing font at all.